# java loop store database and call it back error

Tags: java, sql, database, for-loop, wamp

When created random email and store in mysql database its working fine then i try to print that random email but i can't. Anyone help me where can i edit my code?
Without  `ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from user_data");` and 
`System.out.println(rs.getString(1));` its working fine
note:- someone please edit my grammar

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class new_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String>objectsToStores = new ArrayList<>();

        Random rad = new Random();

        for (int j=1; j<=3; j++ )
        {
            objectsToStores.add("usename"+rad.nextInt()+"@gmail.com");

        }

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ;

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false", "root", "");

            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from user_data");

            for (String x : objectsToStores  ) {

                statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USER_DATA (email) VALUES ('" +x +"')");

            }

while(rs.next())

                System.out.println(rs.getString(1)); 

            connection.commit();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Give us the error stacktrace, and the database schema

Comment: Random rad = new Random(); in this line syntax error

Comment: I can compile your code without any syntax error

Comment: its working ? so my codes are correct?

Comment: wait i'm creating a dummy db to test your code

Comment: thz and plz post your code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the order that you were using for executing queries on the db
I just moved down the line

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from user_data");
```

after

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USER_DATA (email) VALUES ('" + x + "')");
```

This solve the problem because when you execute the UPDATE (second query) the ResultSet from the SELECT
get closed by the statement so you can't iterate it, and give you an error

```
try {
    // This is not needed anymore with the new driver
    //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false", "root", "");

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    for (String x : objectsToStores) {
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USER_DATA (email) VALUES ('" + x + "')");
    }

    // I just moved this line down
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from user_data");
    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

    connection.commit();
    statement.close();
    connection.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```